# form_for with :slug instead of :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @task] do |f| %>
```

gives `users/:id/tasks` but I would need `users/:slug/tasks` as I am using:

```
resources :users, param: :slug do
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

but if I use:

```
<%= form_for [current_user.slug, @task] do |f| %>
```

I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'jemelle_visits_path' for`

how to get `users/jemelle/tasks` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to override the `to_param` method of your model:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

> ```
> user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
> user_path(user)  # => "/users/1"
> ```
>
> You can override to_param in your model to make user_path construct a path using the user’s name instead of the user’s id:
>
> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   def to_param  # overridden
>     name
>   end
> end
>
> user = User.find_by_name('Phusion')
> user_path(user)  # => "/users/Phusion"
> ```

Comment: this surprisingly work.. I told you didn't understand the question at first. Is that #to_param overwriting the method that form_for uses to translate the argument into a path?

Comment: yes it does just that, and I could change User#name to my User#slug

Comment: `form_for` uses the type of the object to infer it has to call `user_path`, and then `user_path` calls `.to_param` on that object (`to_param` defaults to the id)